# How to control music using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone here already tried to control a embedded music using javascript where there are only two buttons which is stop and play

```
function stop(){
//stop the player
}
function resume(){
//resume the player
}
<object>
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <param name="src" value="music.mp3">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
<embed src="music.mp3" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/mp3" />
</object>
<input type="submit" onclick="resume();" value="play" />
<input type="submit" onclick="stop();" value="pause" />
```

I new to javascript so i'm trying to create a function that stop and play the media..

Comment: What sort of embedded music? [`<audio>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)? Or from a particular service?

Comment: Can you show us anything you have tried, so we can help you through the problem?

Comment: Please give the details about your problem, this is not at all good to ask a question.

Comment: Have you considered doing a little bit of research? Like searching in MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement ) or in the  w3 wiki ( http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio )?

Comment: "_Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results..._"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example, it may help you.

[Audio Player](http://www.premiumbeat.com/tech-blog/how-to-make-an-html5-music-player-using-the-audio-tag/)

```
<audio id="player" name="player" src="song.mp3" controls="controls">
</audio>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].play();
            $("#message").text("Music started");
        })

        $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#message").text("Music paused");
        })

        $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
        })
    })
```

Hey, According to your new Modified question, here is the solution, i think, can you just try this once.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DgJnf/)

The code may not play audio, because there is not file uploaded but have no errors,

Comment: how about if i want to consider it it IE8?

Comment: @g3rriascn - C'mon man... Do some research on your own.  Don't drag other people into your world of IE8 pain.

Comment: @jahroy. I already researched that's why I ask someone because I can't find working answers..

Comment: @SAM i tried ur suggestion but it don't work. I can't figure it why. :|

Comment: @jahroy..you win man.. :)